# how to avoid duplicate web service call at same time in the VS Load test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I have some data source for the load test. the web service call should be fully finished one call, then the same data source record could be reused again. but my problem is how do I know this data record is being used. how can I control this in my VS load test?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide more context? What are the test details and why/how are records being reused? My normal recommendation to avoid duplicated concurrent use if a data source entry is to have many more data source lines than the number of virtual users. At least twice as many and preferably much more.

Comment: in my test, I cannot generate much more data source any more. I have to use the limited users. my data is holding data like user and password, each web service call is using the user and password. if there are two same Web service call is happened, the server will send back error message. but I don't want this situation happened. I wish there is some plugin, I can check if now some thread is using this user and password, if yes, I will wait it end, if not, send the web service call.  Is there any example to help monitor the thread I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for synchronizing the use of data source values between virtual users.

One possibility is to put the login request in a loop that keeps on trying until it succeeds. The login request and the loop could be structured as follows:

```
loop "Context parameter exists", Check for existence == false
    Issue the login request
        Extraction rule: "Extract text"
            Search for text such as "Login successful"
            With Required == false
endloop
```

The loop is set to keeps on looping while the context parameter (CP) does not exist. It may be sensible to set a maximum number of iterations of the loop (perhaps 10) just in case the server is not working. That will ensure that the test stops eventually.

The login request is sent and an extraction rule looks for some text that indicates a successful login. If that text is found then something is written to the CP. If the login was not successful then, because `Required == false`, the CP is not created. Hence the loop goes around again.

The login request should probably have a non-zero think time to give the other virtual users time to finish their usage of the data. You could even have a PostRequest plugin that sets the think time to zero if the login was successful. (Note, I think that a PostRequest plugin can modify the think time but you would have to check that this works.)

Understanding the performance of the test will be a little more complex as the overall test time will include the failed login attempts.